# Upgrading from Windows 8 RTM to Release, if there is a difference

Tags: windows, upgrade, windows-8, rtm

So I'm kinda stuck in a hard place. I'm wanting to finally re-install Windows and looking at whether I should stick to tried and true Windows 7 or go with the funky and experimental Windows 8.

As such I've virtualised Windows 8 RTM, looked at its features and GUI and I'm quite impressed, personally. So I'm willing to upgrade to it. However Windows 8's release is just under 50 days away according to Wikipedia and I'm impatient, so if I go to RTM and like it enough to continue using it, will I be able to go to "release" version and receive updates for it as normal or would I have to reinstall again?

Comment: Is this the same question you are asking? http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/will-i-be-able-to-upgrade-windows-8-release/12a00692-1758-4082-a0ec-31e0f666d980

Comment: @user142485 No, I'm asking about RTM to release (general availability), until boxed copies are available etc. Though that depends of course if there is a difference!

Comment: RTM is RTM, it will be no different than what will be officially released in October. What you can do is use the built in "easy transfer" to make a lateral move to W8 when it is released in October.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RTM ***is*** release. It's short for "*Release* to Manufacturing", and it is the final version that will be in stores soon.